# How to use ReadDocumentFeedAsync on DocumentDb .NET SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am simply trying to explore all documents in my Azure DocumentDb collection using a simple .NET console program :

```cs
using (var client = new DocumentClient(serviceEndPoint, authKey))
{
    var feed = client.ReadDocumentFeedAsync(docsLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 }).Result;

    Console.WriteLine("feed.Count = {0}", feed.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("feed.CurrentResourceQuotaUsage = {0}", feed.CurrentResourceQuotaUsage);

    var count = 0;
    foreach (var item in feed)
    {
        count++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Read count = {0}", count);
}
```

My code is based on [the official sample on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/ba40b73023fe396ce8c0e53de958a404120d1db9/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs#L178).

Despite using MaxItemCount = -1 (for dynamic page sizing), I always obtain the following results:

```
feed.Count = 9700
feed.CurrentResourceQuotaUsage = documentSize=612;documentsSize=515130;documentsCount=425200;collectionSize=627243;
Read count = 9700
```

So my collection contains more than 400k documents, but the feeds only returns the first 9700 documents.

The azure portal metrics (and my knowledge) confirm that there are 425k documents :

[image: azure portal screenshot]

I have tried to manually set the `MaxItemCount` but the results stays limited to the first 9700 items.

So, what is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing in your code is handling of continuation tokens. Essentially what is happening is that each request is assigned a certain time to execute and it tries to return maximum data during that alloted time. If there's more data, it returns a continuation token that you would use and execute your query again. Since you want to fetch all records, you will execute the loop till the time service returns you continuation token.

Please see sample code below (I have not tried running it though).

```
        using (var client = new DocumentClient(serviceEndPoint, authKey))
        {
            string continuationToken = null;
            var count = 0;
            do
            {
                var feed = client.ReadDocumentFeedAsync(docsLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, RequestContinuation = continuationToken }).Result;
                continuationToken = feed.ResponseContinuation;
                Console.WriteLine("feed.Count = {0}", feed.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("feed.CurrentResourceQuotaUsage = {0}", feed.CurrentResourceQuotaUsage);
                foreach (var item in feed)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            while (continuationToken != null);

            Console.WriteLine("Read count = {0}", count);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed the  ContinuationToken on the FeedOptions parameter. And the [official sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/ba40b73023fe396ce8c0e53de958a404120d1db9/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs#L178) seems to be misleading.